# Соединить 2 масива

Tags: php

Есть 2 масива вида :

```
$arr_1 = [
    [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'three' => 7,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => '',
    ],

    [
        'one' => 4,
        'two' => 5,
        'three' => 6,
        'four' => 12,
        'five' => '',
    ],

    [
        'one' => 3,
        'two' => 7,
        'three' => 8,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => '',
    ],
];
```

и

```
$arr_2 = [
    [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'three' => 111,
        'four' => '',

    ],

    [
        'one' =>2,
        'two' => 22,
        'three' => 24,
        'four' => 'some value',

    ],

    [
        'one' => 3,
        'two' => 74,
        'three' => 85,
        'four' => 'some value 2',

    ],
];
```

Вопрос следующий, как создать на основе даных масивов новый, при условии

```
if ($arr_1['one'] == $arr_2['one'] ){
```

значение

```
$arr_1['five'] = $arr_2['four']
..............
```

(присваиваем значение 'four' из второго масива к ключу 'five' первого масива)

}

```
else{

записываем старое значение массива `$arr_1`, ничего не меняя 



}
```

Нужный результат:

```
$arr_finish = [

    [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'three' => 7,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => 'some value 3',
    ],
    [
        'one' => 4,
        'two' => 5,
        'three' => 6,
        'four' => 12,
        'five' => '',
    ],
    [
        'one' => 3,
        'two' => 7,
        'three' => 8,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => 'some value 2',
    ],



]
```

То есть, должен получиться новый масив на основе `$arr_1`, в котором при выполнении условия дописываются значения с масива `$arr__2`.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Соединить 2 масива

Вот так например:

```
$arr_1 = [
    [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'three' => 7,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => '',
    ],

    [
        'one' => 4,
        'two' => 5,
        'three' => 6,
        'four' => 12,
        'five' => '',
    ],

    [
        'one' => 3,
        'two' => 7,
        'three' => 8,
        'four' => '',
        'five' => '',
    ],
];

$arr_2 = [
    [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
        'three' => 111,
        'four' => 'some value 3',

    ],

    [
        'one' =>2,
        'two' => 22,
        'three' => 24,
        'four' => 'some value',

    ],

    [
        'one' => 3,
        'two' => 74,
        'three' => 85,
        'four' => 'some value 2',

    ],
];

$res = [];
// Массивы одной длины
foreach($arr_1 as $key => $val){
    // Присвоил массив
    $res[$key] = $arr_1[$key];
    // Только при условии меняет 
    if($arr_1[$key]['one'] === $arr_2[$key]['one']){
        $res[$key]['five'] = $arr_2[$key]['four'];
    }

}
print_r($res);
```

Вот такой результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 2
            [three] => 7
            [four] => 
            [five] => some value 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [one] => 4
            [two] => 5
            [three] => 6
            [four] => 12
            [five] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [one] => 3
            [two] => 7
            [three] => 8
            [four] => 
            [five] => some value 2
        )

)
```